# Determining user base growth with multilevel modeling - how to interpret

Tags: regression, mixed-model, python, random-effects-model, statsmodels

#### **Background**

I'll start by saying that I'm not sure whether to use Multilevel Modeling or Vector Autoregression for this problem. I have panel data, which tracks users who log into my website over time. I record purchase behavior, time of purchase, user ID, and location of user. Data are aggregated on a per-day basis. So for any given day, I have recorded the number of purchases for a user, the country they are in when they logged into the site, and the total number of purchases for the day.

These data are also not sampled. I have the whole shebang.

```
user_id = User ID
time = Time user logged in
user_location = User location (0: USA, 1: France, 2: Germany)
purchase_volume = Number of purchases
```

---

#### **Question**

I want to understand the differences in purchasing volume over time for my users (are users in Germany buying at a faster rate than users in France?). It's the issue of RATE here that confuses me in terms of how I approach this problem. From what I've learned, I need a multilevel model, which should be able to describe how my customers grow in their purchasing volume at separate rates in different countries.

So I use mixedlm in statsmodels and use the following code. I include a random intercept for user, and I allow those intercepts to vary randomly as a function of time.

```
md = smf.mixedlm("purchase_volume ~ time * C(country)", 
                 groups="user_id", 
                 re_formula="~time", 
                 data=data)
mdf = md.fit(method=["lbfgs"])
print(mdf.summary())

Mixed Linear Model Regression Results
===============================================================
Model:              MixedLM Dependent Variable: purchase_volume
No. Observations:   861     Method:             REML           
No. Groups:         72      Scale:              5.9993         
Min. group size:    11      Likelihood:         -2217.5256     
Max. group size:    12      Converged:          Yes            
Mean group size:    12.0                                       
---------------------------------------------------------------
                     Coef.  Std.Err.   z    P>|z| [0.025 0.975]
---------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept            15.872    0.613 25.884 0.000 14.671 17.074
C(country)[T.1]       0.433    0.480  0.903 0.366 -0.507  1.374
C(country)[T.2]      -0.880    0.479 -1.836 0.066 -1.819  0.060
time                  6.929    0.089 78.071 0.000  6.755  7.103
time:C(country)[T.1] -0.081    0.066 -1.212 0.226 -0.211  0.050
time:C(country)[T.2]  0.116    0.067  1.738 0.082 -0.015  0.247
user_id Var          19.377    1.556                           
user_id x time Cov    0.298    0.152                           
time Var              0.415    0.033                           
===============================================================
```

---

#### **Confusion**

Now I can see that I have an overall effect of time, and no real effect of country or interaction of country with time. However, the variances are still a mystery to me: How do these values help me understand how my users grow at different rates? What extra analysis do I need to do to determine this specific piece? My initial thoughts were to do some sort of post hoc within subjects ANOVA, but that feels wrong. I mean, why not just make this an ANOVA to begin with then?

With that being said, I'm also confused whether I should use a VAR model instead for this problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you have 72 users who made a total of 861 purchases, and the number of purchases per user is extremely consistent, ranging only from 11 to 12.

Ideally, time should be translated so that time=0 is meaningful.

The purchase sizes are getting larger over time.  There are no detectable differences between countries, either in their starting levels (at time=0), or in their rate of change over time.

The variances describe differences in behavior between individual users.  The user intercept has an SD of sqrt(19.4) ~ 4, so a typical user consistently purchases 4-8 units more volume or less volume (1-2 SD) than the mean. The individual time slope has SD sqrt(0.4) ~ 0.6.  So the common slope (6.3) is modulated by around +/- 1.2 (2 SD) between individuals.